# How to download hadoop vm appliances?

Tags: windows, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, cygwin, virtual-machine

I am new to hadoop technology. I am installing hadoop on windows. I am unable to get vm appliances. How can I download hadoop vm ware appliances 1.2.1?

Comment: So you want to install VMware on window and then hadoop on it ??

Comment: Yes. I want to install hadoop.